# Is it okay if I undo traces in EasyEDA?

Tags: pcb, pcb-assembly, eda

I'm new to PCB design.  I am using EasyEDA. I'm currently designing a PCB with around 50 connections. I did 48 of them myself and ran the AutoRouter for the other two. The AutoRouter has made the other 48 traces again as well (on top of the existing traces.) Is this okay, or do I have to manually remove all the duplicate traces?

Comment: The final output of a pcb design is a gerber file, which doesn't care how many traces are on top each other, with gerbers what you see is what you get, so no doesn't matter. that said don't use auto routing, it's bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this might be okay for now, it could be asking for trouble down the line. Even if your DRC doesn't show any problems, the DRC of your fabricator maybe will depending on how you are transferring your data.

If those traces are an exact copy, I don't think it's very likely that something will go wrong when transferring the data with gerbers. Gerbers are just two dimensional after all.

However, in PCB design one should always be extra careful with data exchange as things can go wrong where you don't expect them to. Maybe your auto-router duplicated drills for vias as well, for example. And those drills might end up duplicated in your Excellon file and raise some eyebrows at your fabrication shop.

Personally, I wouldn't have a good feeling not cleaning this up.

Answer (score 1):

If the traces are crossing / touching places they should not, then yes you will need to clean up the duplicates.

Comment: They lie exactly on top of each other, in the same layer. And the Design Rule Check is showing no problems.

Comment: Then there should be no issues, most projects when they get to the gerber generation stage will have random segments of other traces overlapping others.

Answer (score 0):

A note for next time, you can skip nets you don't want the auto router to route in Auto Router Config

[image: Skip nets]

Also if you want to just nuke everything and start again, you can hit Route > Unroute all

[image: Unroute all]